# xeCJK doesn't find a font from file

Tags: xecjk

So far I successfully used a Chinese font from a file. Now I decided to use the package xeCJK and my setup does not work anymore. Would you please suggest what should I add for xeCJK?

In an example below, if the line `\usecjktrue` is commented-out, then the file is compiled successfully and I get Chinese letters in pdf. If `\usecjktrue` is active, then the error message is:

```
kpathsea: Running mktextfm ukai
...
! I can't find file `ukai'.
...
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! The font "ukai" cannot be found.
```

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\DeclareFontFamily{EU1}{ukai}{}
\DeclareFontShape{EU1}{ukai}{m}{n}{ <-> "[ukai.ttc]"}{}

\newif\ifusecjk
%\usecjktrue % uncomment to use xeCJK and fail

\ifusecjk
 \usepackage[BoldFont,SlantFont]{xeCJK}
 \setCJKmainfont{ukai}
 \setCJKsansfont{ukai}
 \setCJKmonofont{ukai}
\fi
\begin{document}
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "zh"\relax
\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 1pt minus 0.5pt \relax
\ifusecjk\else
  \renewcommand\rmdefault{ukai}
  \fontencoding{\encodingdefault}\fontfamily{\rmdefault}\selectfont
\fi

危险
\end{document}
```

Comment: Go to this website  http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/source/lucid/ttf-arphic-ukai and download the font `ttf-arphic-ukai` to your font directory in the system. This should make your problem go away.

Comment: The font is in the same directory where the test file is located. The font file is found when xeCJK is not used.

Comment: No. I don't know what your system is. In my window system, I put the font into the `\control panel\font` directory, then it compiles fine.

Comment: @jesse: even if you uncomment the line "\usecjktrue"?

Comment: NO, it compiles when \usecjktrue is commented out. It seems that I was directed to the issue of missing font file in the system.

Answer (score 2):

If you read Chinese, you should read the documentation of the `xeCJK` package.

The `xeCJK` package could access font file directly. That is, `\DeclareFontFamily` and `\DeclareFontShape` are superfluous here.

BTW, the package has already handled the line break issue. `\XeTeXlinebreaklocale` and `\XeTeXlinebreaklocale` are also superfluous.

According to your code, a minimal working example could be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[BoldFont,SlantFont]{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{ukai.ttc}

\begin{document}

Some latin letters
危险
Latin letters again
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is very helpful to me.  I got error because I didn't use the full file-name with extension, `ukai.ttc`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that xeCJK uses `\fontspec` instead of `\selectfont`:

```
> \xeCJK@font@rm=macro:
->\fontspec [BoldFont={ukai},BoldFeatures={RawFeature={embolden=4}},ItalicFont=
{ukai},ItalicFeatures={RawFeature={slant=0.17}},BoldItalicFont={ukai},BoldItali
cFeatures={RawFeature={embolden=4,slant=0.17}}]{ukai}.
l.17 \show\xeCJK@font@rm
```

Quite expensive. With forced change to `\selectfont` I get what I need:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}% get "EU1"
\DeclareFontFamily{EU1}{ukai}{}
\DeclareFontShape{EU1}{ukai}{m}{n}{ <-> "[ukai.ttc]"}{}

\usepackage[BoldFont,SlantFont]{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{ukai}
\setCJKsansfont{ukai}
\setCJKmonofont{ukai}

\begin{document}
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "zh"\relax
\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 1pt minus 0.5pt \relax

\makeatletter
\show\xeCJK@font@rm
\def\xeCJK@font@rm{\fontfamily{ukai}\selectfont}
\makeatother

Some latin letters
危险
Latin letters again
\end{document}
```